# C# Copy powerpoint Master Slide layout

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I want to copy master layout from one presentation to another. 
If I wanted to copy a slide the code would be `Presentation.Slides[1].Copy`, however I can't find similar code for copying master layout. There is  `Presentation.SlideMaster.Delete()` but for some reason there is no copy. If it is not possible in c# is it possible in vba??

I want to basically automate [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-and-paste-a-slide-master-from-one-presentation-to-another-ab99cf07-3a65-4f50-9d24-f17444a3df9b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the VBA code to copy a design from one presentation to the other - http://skp.mvps.org/pptxp018.htm. The same is achievable in C#.

```
Sub CopyDesigns()

    Dim oSourceDesigns As Presentation
    Dim I As Integer
    Set oSourceDesigns = Presentations.Open("K:\Docs\main.pot", , , False)
    
    For I = 1 To oSourceDesigns.Designs.Count
        ActivePresentation.Designs.Clone oSourceDesigns.Designs(I)
    Next I
    
    oSourceDesigns.Close
    Set oSourceDesigns = Nothing

End Sub
```